# Fourier transformation by differentiating a function and integrating the solution.

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Is the integral of the Fourier transform of derivative a function equal to the Fourier transform of the function?

For an example, I have a function $\theta(x)=-2\tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{c})$.

I find computing Fourier transform of this function quite difficult. So, I was planning to take the derivative of the function.
$$\theta'(x)=-\frac{2}{c \left(\frac{x^2}{c^2}+1\right)}$$
I can easily compute the Fourier transform of this function
$\theta'(p)=\sqrt{2 \pi } \left(-e^{-c | p| }\right)$.
Integrating on both sides:
$\theta(p)=\frac{| p|  \left(\sqrt{2 \pi } e^{-c | p| }\right)}{c p}$

Is this the correct Fourier transform of the function $\theta(x)$?

Comment: $\theta(x)$ is not integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ because it has finite, non-zero limits at $\pm\infty$. This cannot be carried out in a classical sense. How are you trying to carry this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true. The FT of $f'$ is $-it \hat {f} (t)$. So to find $\hat {f} (t)$ you have to just divide $\hat {f'}(t)$ by $-it$ instead of integrating it.